# Missing the Edit button

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am a novice and reluctant SharePoint administrator. I created a sub-site for someone at work and gave them control of it. Now this person comes back to me and says the Edit button is gone from the top of the ribbon.

We are running SharePoint Foundation 2010.

What is remaining on the top of the ribbon, from left to right...

Site Actions menu, Navigate Up, Browse, Page.

How do I get Edit back?

Comment: Do you see the 'edit' button before? Notice that not every page in SharePoint can be edited. If it cannot be edited the icon will not be shown. If I remember correctly, only pages under /site pages/ or /pages/ can be edited.

Answer (score 1):

The user has to have the correct permissions assigned to them before the Edit page option will appear. You'll have to go into Site Settings, and under "Users and Permissions" click on Advanced Permissions". Add the user or AD group to the "Design" SharePoint group. Or you could make your own permission level, create your own SharePoint group, and assign that permission level to the group. Then add the user(s) you want, and when they login they'll see the "Edit Page" option in the "Site Actions' menu.

You can also provide the site collection administrator or Site owner permission to the user to see more options.

Comment: Thank you but I have Full control and cannot see the Edit button either. And I am on SP Foundation....no Advanced Permissions are under Site settings.

Comment: Edit page button?

Comment: @Aanchal, he is using SP2010 not SP2013. There is a small "edit" icon at the right of "Navigate Up" icon.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page is checked in.  If it is checked out, only the person who has the page checked out can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**Symptoms**
Only 'new button' no edit. The top ribbon had 'quick edit' greyed out - hovering over gave the following message:

"This control is currently disabled ....."

**Solution:**
Top menu > List > Modify View > Scroll down and expand 'Tabular view' > tick box (Allow individual item checkboxes)

I had this disabled previously for a cleaner look, however adding or removing tabular view causes this error.

I hope this helps someone.